# How to deal with non-UK 'diplomas' when sending a CV to a UK company?

Tags: resume, job-search, united-kingdom

I got a handful of serious (not from a diploma mill) specialized short courses with the word 'Diploma' on them. They were all company sponsored training.

The issue here is that 'diploma' in the UK seems to be understood as an academic level, which implies significant efforts to obtain (but less than a bachelor).

I would not like to appear as some kind of trickster, who claims to have a batch of academic credentials that happen to be faux. However, I also don't see how I could express this situation to the HR guy, who will probably just skim through the CV.

Comment: Just put them under a section on your CV as something like _"Industry Short Courses"_.  This could be directly under any other education section you have.

Answer (score 3):

I would list them in their best light under 'qualifications' and explain duration etc,. if asked. If it says it's a diploma, then it's a diploma in that locale.

Employers are aware that it varies from locale to locale and will ask if they have any concerns. I take all these sorts of 'diploma's' with a large grain of salt, many of them tend to be unfailable. So I'll ask if I see something interesting.

This applies to any qualifications, a degree from the National University of Samoa is still a degree, notwithstanding the fact that it doesn't prove you actually know anything about anything.